# How can I open modal view without loosing data in target controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiwebview, storyboard

The problem is that I have no idea how can I save received controller data after pushing it or presenting as modal view. I am using storyboard, ARC, iOS5. When project was using xib everything worked fine. I have UIWebView in target ViewController and I need it to open transmitted url for twitter OAuth authentication. Here is code of TweetViewController, from where I call function of WebViewController. Then I try to present UIViewController where UIWebController is. But after i transmit url, it forgets this data. So on ViewDidLoad function the NSURL is null.

```
// TweetViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RSTwitterEngine.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface TweetViewController : UIViewController <RSTwitterEngineDelegate, WebViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) RSTwitterEngine *twitterEngine;
@property (strong, nonatomic) WebViewController *leWebView;

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sendButton;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;

- (IBAction)sendTweet:(id)sender;
- (void)swipedRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;

@end
```

Part of TweetViewController.m which sends url data:

```
#pragma mark - RSTwitterEngine Delegate Methods

- (void)twitterEngine:(RSTwitterEngine *)engine needsToOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self.leWebView = [_leWebView initWithURL:url];
    self.leWebView.delegate = self;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LeWebSegue" sender:self];      
    //[self presentModalViewController:self.leWebView animated:YES];
}
```

So here is WebViewController key parts:

```
//  WebViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol WebViewControllerDelegate;

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURL *currentURL;

@property (assign, nonatomic) id <WebViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *leWebView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *leActivityIndicator;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (IBAction)ActionNoMore:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol WebViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)dismissWebView;
- (void)handleURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

and  WebViewController.m

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize currentURL = _currentURL;
@synthesize leWebView = _leWebView;
@synthesize leActivityIndicator = _leActivityIndicator;

#pragma mark - Initialization
// ======= Here is that function which recieves url ========
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];
    NSLog(@"WebViewController initWithURL called. Recieved url = %@", url);

    if (self) {
        self.currentURL = url;
        self.delegate = nil;
    }

    return self;

}

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"WebViewController viewDidLoad called. currentURL = %@", self.currentURL);

    self.leWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.leWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.currentURL]];     
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setLeWebView:nil];
    [self setLeActivityIndicator:nil];

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)LeWebView:(UIWebView *)LeWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"rstwitterengine"] && (self.delegate)) {
        if (self.leActivityIndicator) [self.leActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [self.delegate handleURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)LeWebView
{
    if (self.leActivityIndicator) [self.leActivityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)LeWebView
{
    if (self.leActivityIndicator) [self.leActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)LeWebView:(UIWebView *)LeWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.leActivityIndicator) [self.leActivityIndicator stopAnimating];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

#pragma mark - Custom Methods


- (IBAction)ActionNoMore:(id)sender {
    if (self.delegate) [self.delegate dismissWebView];

}
@end
```

At all, when I try to load that view, i receive log messages that **WebViewController viewDidLoad called. currentURL = (null)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I noticed is that you are calling the storyboard to create your view controller in the initWithURL method. The normal way an object is created is the do an alloc and then the initWithURL.  The alloc method creates the object in memory and the initWithURL configures the object.  If you are calling the alloc and then in your initWithURL you are calling the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier you may be creating a memory leak since instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier also allocates memory when it's called.  Then you set the "self" to another address.

This may be causing confusion when you run instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.  It's difficult to say.  You should probably run the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier in the parent view controller and then push your view controller and then set your URL since UIWebViews only instantiate when they are displayed and not when the view controller is created.

HTH

Comment: Glad you found it.  But just to be safe you may also want to check for a memory leak around your initWithURL method.  I can't be sure but it is possible you may be leaking when you run the storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.  Good Luck!